# how to extend class bassed view

Tags: python, django

I've crated class-based-view which shows content of the post.I also added the ability to make comments there, however the comment form dosn't work.

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Post
    template_name='blogdetail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg='id'
   


    def comments(request):
        comments=post.comments.all()
        new_comment=None
        if request.method=="POST":
            comment_form=CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                new_comment=comment_form.save(committ=False)
                new_comment.post=post
                new_comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form=CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'allblogs.html', {'comments':comments, 'comment_form':comment_form,
        'new_comment':new_comment})
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=['post','body']
```

blogdetail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.created_on}}</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'userpage' post.author.username %}"></a>:{{post.author}}</p>
<p>{{post.text}}</p>
<form>
{{comment_form.as_p}}
<p><input type="submit" value="add"></p>
{% csrf_token %}
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Why do you imagine your `comments` function would get called at all? What does your `urls.py` look like? I think you're misunderstanding CBVs very fundamentally here.

Answer (score 0):

class base views are not working this way.
If you look at your class, you didn't call your comment function.
I suggest you look at [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).
Besides that, for creating a URL for your author, I suggest you use [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) in your model and use it in your template like this:
{{ author.get_absolute_url }}

Hope that this answer is helped you.